# Use of auto_remove and force_pull in the Airflow DockerOperator not very clear from documentation

Tags: airflow, dockeroperator

If `force_pull` is not set to True does that mean that if there is an update to the image it will not be pulled. I dont want to pull the image if it does not need to be pulled i.e. there is no change.

Also is `auto-remove` required and what is the danger if the container is not removed if it used repeatedly.

The documentation seems to be pretty light and most articles dont seem to cover these aspects. Can anyone shed more light on these two parameters?

Answer (score 1):

**force_pull** : Pull the docker image on every run (if set to True, Default is False), meaning no updates if it is False.

Anyway, its not recommended to work with tag "latest" so no updates should be unless you change manually the image_id

**auto_remove** : Auto-removal of the container on daemon side when the container’s process exits (its like set **rm** when docker run).

If set to False, every time a new container will be created.

In case you set a container_name then in the second time you will get failure (container with same name exists)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Helps greatly. In the case of airflow is there an advantage of setting auto_remove to true? Does it free up resources as opposed to leaving it false?

Comment: @SudeepAmin, i am usually set it to true. Otherwise a container with status exit is left everytime a dockeroperator is finished.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. If I have a DAG with multiple steps that use the same docker image but calling different entry points in the container, all chained together, if I set auto_remove for each step I am assuming that it will add to the load time because a container has to be created for each step and then removed. What would you recommend in this case?

Comment: @SudeepAmin, I made a simple test of your case and I ended with 2 exit containers. which mean Airflow run for each task different container and not using any existing. so if you leave auto_remove=False you'll get many exist containers as the number of tasks * Dags you are running. if time is critical (you need to make a test with and without auto_remove) then leave it as auto_remove=False and create BashOperator that removes those containers at the end.